# RelativeLayout in ScrollView Error

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to make a form that has many `textView` and `editText` controls so I tried using `scrollview` because the screen won't be able to display all of them.

But when I added to a certain set of textview and scrollview, the next one appears on the top side of the screen instead of below the previous set.

Below is my xml, Please help!

XML FILE :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".InsertJob" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="358dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/JobNameTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="@string/name" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/JobNameET"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/JobNameTV"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/JobNameTV"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/JobNameTV"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/JobDateTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/JobNameTV"
            android:layout_below="@+id/JobNameET"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:text="@string/date" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/JobDateET"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/JobDateTV"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/JobDateTV"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/JobNameET"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/date_example"
            android:inputType="date" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/JobTimeStartTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/JobDateTV"
            android:layout_below="@+id/JobDateTV"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:text="Jam Mulai" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/JobTimeStartET"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/JobTimeStartTV"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/JobTimeStartTV"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/JobDateET"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/timeexample"
            android:inputType="time" />   

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/JobTimeEndTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/JobDateTV"
            android:layout_below="@+id/JobTimeStartTV"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:text="Jam Selesai" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/JobTimeEndET"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/JobTimeEndTV"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/JobTimeEndTV"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/JobDateET"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/timeexample"
            android:inputType="time" />   

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/JobPlaceTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/JobTimeEndTV"
            android:layout_below="@+id/JobTimeEndET"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:text="@string/place" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/JobPlaceET"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/JobPlaceTV"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/JobPlaceTV"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/JobTimeEndET"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/JobDetailTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/JobPlaceTV"
            android:layout_below="@+id/JobPlaceET"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:text="Detail" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/JobDetailET"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/JobPlaceET"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/JobDetailTV"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/SongListTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/JobDetailTV"
            android:layout_below="@+id/JobDetailET"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Lagu 1" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/SongListET"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/JobDetailET"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/SongListTV"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/LogoutBtn"
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/logout"
    android:onClick="logout" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ConfirmBtn"
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/LogoutBtn"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/confirm" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".InsertJob" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="358dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="20dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/JobNameTV"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="@string/name" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/JobNameET"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/JobNameTV"
                android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/JobNameTV"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/JobDateTV"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/JobNameET"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:text="@string/date" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/JobDateET"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/JobNameET"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/JobDateTV"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/JobDateTV"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/date_example"
                android:inputType="date" >

            </EditText>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/JobTimeStartTV"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/JobDateTV"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:text="Jam Mulai" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/JobTimeStartET"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/JobDateET"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/JobTimeStartTV"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/JobTimeStartTV"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/timeexample"
                android:inputType="time" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/JobTimeEndTV"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/JobTimeStartTV"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:text="Jam Selesai" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/JobTimeEndET"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/JobTimeStartET"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/JobTimeEndTV"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/JobTimeEndTV"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/timeexample"
                android:inputType="time" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/JobPlaceTV"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/JobTimeEndTV"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:text="@string/place" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/JobPlaceET"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/JobTimeEndET"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/JobPlaceTV"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/JobPlaceTV"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="text" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/JobDetailTV"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/JobPlaceTV"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:text="Detail" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/JobDetailET"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/JobPlaceET"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/JobDetailTV"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/JobDetailTV"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/SongListTV"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/JobDetailTV"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="Lagu 1" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/SongListET"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/JobDetailET"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/SongListTV"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/SongListTV"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="text" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/LogoutBtn"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/logout"
        android:onClick="logout" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ConfirmBtn"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/LogoutBtn"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/confirm" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: wow, from a glance your code doesn't seem to be so different from mine and an answer bellow. But it helps and I can even add 4 more sets and still works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. `EditText` JobDateET is missing attribute `"android:layout_layout_below="@+id/JobDateTV"`
2. `EditText` JobTimeStartET is missing attribute `"android:layout_layout_below="@+id/JobTimeStartTV"`
3. `EditText` JobTimeStartET is missing attribute `"android:layout_layout_below="@+id/JobTimeStartTV"`

Comment: they all are set to follow their textview (the same named textview) the one that have the error is SongListTV and bellow

Answer (score 0):

Try this.......

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/SongListTV"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/JobDetailTV"
     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
     android:text="Lagu 1"/>
```

Comment: it did worked for the songlist textview, but when I added another one below, it happened again.

Comment: I added a textview like this below SongListTV it was ok..... <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dsfgh"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            
            android:layout_below="@+id/SongListTV"
           
           android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Lagsfdgu 1" />

Comment: hmm.. why mine's not ok? I even copied your code and still got the same result

Comment: the other answer has helped me. but thanks for your help too. I appreciate it